# ATL COM ErrorInfo in javascript

Tags: exception, error-handling, com, atl, jscript

Using [ISupportErrorInfo and IErrorInfo](http://www.delphigroups.info/3/bd/55531.html) is possible to provide rich error info.

This approach allows to use: SetDescription, SetHelpFile, SetSource and SetHelpContext to detail the error.

**Is it possible to retrieve theses properties in javascript?**

example:

```js
try
{
    var obj = new ActiveXObject("ATLCOM.MyClass");
    obj.functionThrowError();
}
catch(ex)
{
    ex.message // IErrorInfo::getDescription();
    ex.?? // IErrorInfo::getHelpFile();
    ex.?? // IErrorInfo::getSource(); 
    ex.?? // IErrorInfo::getHelpContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dww52sbt) does not pick all `IErrorInfo` properties so you don't have them available on JS code.